# Anonymous LDAP query - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

so I have Windows Server 2012 which is running on my virtual machine. I want to have possibility to make anonymous query against LDAP. For example if I'm using software like [Softerra LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/) I need to run this program as domain user to be able browse AD groups/users etc. But my point is that I want to be able to do it also as non-domain user(anonymous), or at least using domain user credentials from machine that is not part of the domain.

I was looking for this option in user/group policies, I've grant my user with all privileges that I found - but always with the same result - I was unable to browse LDAP.

So my question is - what have to bet set/changed to be able make anonymous queries against Windows Server LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about anonymous queries, but you said that  you would also be happy using a domain user from a non-domain machine.
That should work fine.  Create a domain user with sufficient privileges to see what you want.
Install a certificate on your LDAP server (or use Kerberos, but that's more annoying on the non-domain machine).
Then do LDAP authentication using the username and password of that domain user.
It works well.

Comment: I tried that. But i got "Invalid username or password". But if I run this software("Run as..." from context menu) as this same user - everything works fine. But that's my issue - I want to be able to use same credentials when this program is running in my local machine user context.

Comment: I'd recommend debugging this using an LDAP client that does not use domain credentials; that uses username and password you specify to the client and is entirely uneffected by run-as